# SVN Repository Dictated Configuration: pattern overriding not working as expected

Tags: svn

I have an SVN config file which I must not alter. This config file defines some rules for automatic property assignment. Here is the relevant part of the config file:

```
enable-auto-props = yes
[auto-props]
*.xlsm = svn:needs-lock=*
```

For one specific repository, I do NOT want to have the property `svn:needs-lock` assigned to `*.xlsm` files. For this purpose I want to use the "Repository Dictated Configuration". I assign the property `svn:auto-props` with value `*.xlsm = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.ms-excel` to the repository root.

According to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SVN/Inheritable-Ignores-AutoProps#Inheritable-Ignores-AutoProps-Auto-PropsHierarchyandPrecedence) information, the pattern `*.xlsm` from the property `svn:auto-props` overrides the pattern from the config file, as long as I add files to the respective repository root and their children.

Example:

```
/               Repository root with the "svn:auto-props" property
                assigned, as described above.
/file.xlsm      The file I want to add to the repo.
```

When adding the file `file.xlsm`, I expect the properties of that file to be

```
svn:mime-type    application/vnd.ms-excel
```

since `svn:auto-props` from the repository root overrides the pattern from my config file. However, the rules seem to be merged and the resulting properties for `file.xlsm` are:

```
svn:mime-type    application/vnd.ms-excel
svn:needs-lock   *
```

My understanding of overriding is the replacement of one rule by another, not applying both rules at the same time. How can I achieve the result I expect?

I am running Windows 10 and SVN 1.9.5:

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.9.5 (r1770682)
   compiled Nov 26 2016, 14:22:31 on x86-microsoft-windows

Copyright (C) 2016 The Apache Software Foundation.
```

Update: I have installed the latest version of SVN now which didn't fix the problem.

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.11.1 (r1850623)
   compiled Jan  9 2019, 19:28:50 on x86-microsoft-windows

Copyright (C) 2019 The Apache Software Foundation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the behavior of overriding wrongly in this case.

Not patterns are overridden, but properties are overridden. This means that if I define a property twice, then overriding applies as defined for the value of the property, not for the whole pattern.

Unfortunately, overriding is broken as of now. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-4699

Furthermore, overriding `svn:needs-lock` is impossible if it was set once. `svn:needs-lock` takes no value, the property stands for itself. I can only override a property by defining a new value (I can still assign any value to that property, but this does not change the behavior).

This means for my case: I have defined `svn:needs-lock` in my SVN config file. `svn:needs-lock` is enabled now. I cannot override this property such that it becomes deleted.

**There is no solution to my question.**